# How do I parse out the substrings in python?

Tags: python

I need to parse out the following:

```
2012
01
02
16
50
00
```

out of the string (in this format):

```
2012-01-02 16:50:00 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABC
```

What's a simple command that would accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a datetime value, or only the individual numeric componensts?

Comment: Individual components. But I would be interested about the datetime value? I could not find any way to convert it to seconds in version  below 2.7....If there is a way to convert this straight to seconds, that would help, too.

Answer (score 5):

Don't parse out the individual components; go straight for a `datetime.datetime()` object:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstr[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You can still get the individual components from that:

```
dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, ...
```

or format them back to zero-padded strings:

```
[format(v, '02') for v in dt.timetuple()[:6]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> inputstr = '2012-01-02 16:50:00 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABC'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstr[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> dt.year, dt.month, dt.day
(2012, 1, 2)
>>> [format(v, '02') for v in dt.timetuple()[:6]]
['2012', '01', '02', '16', '50', '00']
```

To turn the `datetime` value to seconds since the epoch, use `time.mktime()` or `calendar.timegm()`, depending on your needs:

```
>>> from time import mktime
>>> mktime(dt.timetuple())
1325523000.0
>>> from calendar import timegm
>>> timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
1325523000
```

Without a timezone there is no difference between these two methods, with a timezone the latter will always return the time as UTC.

Comment: `map('{:02}'.format, dt.timetuple()[:6])` or `[format(el, '02') for el in dt.timetuple()[:6]]` or whatever ya fancy ;) meets the parse requirements I believe

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s='2012-01-02 16:50:00 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABC'
>>> s.split()[0].split('-')+s.split()[1].split(':')
['2012', '01', '02', '16', '50', '00']
```